# How to deploy a "build" folder on Heroku created with create react app (npm run build)?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, deployment, build

I want to "upload" this build folder to Heroku. I do not to run the build process instead just tell Heroku to download the files from this folder when I run `npm run build` or when I click "deploy" in Heroku? Is that possible and how do I do that?

[image]

Comment: Why don't you want Heroku to build your application itself? Committing build artifacts is an antipattern.

Comment: @Chris Herok-22 does not allow to build create reach app anymore.

Comment: Yes, the third-party `mars/create-react-app` buildpack is deprecated. But that doesn't mean you should be building outside of Heroku. Just make sure your `build` script provides the right build command and use [one of the workarounds for static hosting](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=heroku+static+hosting). (Better yet, use a more appropriate tool for the job. Heroku is meant to _run code_, not host static sites. Even with the old buildpack it was a poor fit.)